# PHP : Difference between '&&' and 'AND'

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - and / or keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502092/php-and-or-keywords)

Dear All,

I would like to get clear in mind about conditional operators in php. Please clarify me what is the difference between '&&' and 'AND' in php?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please search for existing questions before you ask a new one.

Comment: @middaparka: In all fairness, it's pretty hard to search for "&&" or "AND".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They do the same thing, but `&&` has higher precedence than `AND`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: While correct, pick one style and stick to it. Unless you LIKE leaving code bombs for people to blow limbs off with.

Comment: Dear Dampe, I couldn't understand what would you like to say.

Comment: @JimMischel Try the following: `define( 'THIS', true ); $test_a = defined( 'THIS' ) AND THIS ? 'A: success' : 'A: no success';  $test_b = defined( 'THIS' ) AND THIS ? 'A: success' : 'A: no success'; var_dump( $test_a ); echo '<br />'; var_dump( $test_b );`. If I'm not wrong, then `$test_a` is `TRUE` and `$test_b` would be `A success`, right?

Comment: @kaiser no, they are both `bool (true)`

Comment: An easier example: `$a = 1 AND 1 OR false; $b = 1 &&  1 OR false;`
After this `$a` will be == 1 (and the rest of the expression is just omitted), while `$b` will be == true because this is the result of the whole expression.

Comment: The easiest example: `$a = true AND false;`. Can you guess the $a? It will be = TRUE !!!