# PHP: OR and ||, AND and &&

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I am know about priority, but if we have one simple condition:

```
if ($a == 1 AND $b == 2){

}
```

Is there any difference with

```
if ($a == 1 && $b == 2){

}
```

?

Comment: No difference with `==`. Compare with [PHP operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

Comment: a bit OOT, what funny for me is, the fact that CI suggests users to use OR instead of ||, but choosing && instead of AND... such an inconsistency...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference at all, except that perhaps using `AND` is somewhat more readable.

EDIT: just checked, and there is a small difference in the operators precedence, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 4):

They do the exact same thing. `&&` has higher precedence that `AND` though.

This has been asked before:

[PHP - and / or keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502092/php-and-or-keywords)

[PHP : Difference between '&&' and 'AND'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511240/php-difference-between-and-and)

Comment: I believe I can fly. I believe I can touch the sky.

Answer (score 1):

The both work the same in php, but most programmers are used to using && as its the syntax used in most programming languages

Comment: Yes, i am now about it, but AND more readable and easy to type it =)