# What is the difference between 'and, or' and '&&, ||'?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [PHP - and / or keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502092/php-and-or-keywords)
>   [Ruby: difference between || and 'or'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083112/ruby-difference-between-and-or)

What is the difference between this:

```
a=20
b=30
if (a > 10 && b > 10)
    puts a
end
```

and this:

```
if (a > 10 and b > 10)
puts a
end
```

and also explain difference between "||" and "or"

Comment: Why did you tag this as PHP? I removed the PHP tag and changed the Rails tag to just Ruby, since the code examples are Ruby (or invalid PHP :P). Many answers here are talking about PHP however. I'm sorry for the confusion. (It seems the answer is the same in both languages, though.)

Comment: Since you tagged `[php]` and all the current answers are linking to the PHP documentation, I've marked this as an exact duplicate of [PHP - and / or keywords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502092/php-and-or-keywords), where you will find the exact same answers.

Comment: I have found the answer for my question. I have posted the answer below. Please review that. thanks to all.

Answer (score 7):

**The answer relates to the `PHP` tag that has been assigned to this question, but has been deleted afterwards**

They are the same with one small difference. The `and` and `or` operator have a [lower precedence](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) compared to `&&` and `||`.

Take this example from the [manual](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php):

```php
// The result of the expression (true && false) is assigned to $g
// Acts like: ($g = (true && false))
$g = true && false;

// The constant true is assigned to $h and then false is ignored
// Acts like: (($h = true) and false)
$h = true and false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read about [operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) in PHP's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Only the difference in [precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: I knew the operator precedence in php. It's not a suitable answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the precedence table for [Ruby](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#table_18.4), the difference is also precedence, as it is in PHP: `and` and `or` have lower precedence than `&&` and `||`.

But there is a slight difference from PHP: in Ruby, `and` and `or` have the same precedence.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. Please go and read it. this is what i'm expect it.

http://avdi.org/devblog/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/

Thanks all of your efforts