# What does "or" in php mean?

Tags: php, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - and / or keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502092/php-and-or-keywords)

I saw several bits of PHP code using `or` in a way I was unfamiliar with. For example:

```
fopen($site,"r") or die("Unable to connect to $site");
```

Is this equal to this `||`?

Why would you use this instead of a `try catch` block? What will cause the program run the `or die()`?

Comment: Got a gun to your head: *Open the file or die!*

Comment: *(related)* [What does that symbol mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: You know, I don't think this is a duplicate. It's really a question about what "expression or die" means.

Answer (score 9):

It is for the most part, but...

> The reason for the two different
>   variations of "and" and "or" operators
>   is that they operate at different
>   precedences.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 2):

`or` is equal to `||` **except** that `||` has a higher presedense than `or`.

Reference:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 1):

`or` has an other precedence. The concrete statement is little trick with boolean operators. Like in a common `if`-test-expression the second part is only executed, if the first is evaluated to `false`. This means, if `fopen()` does not fail, `die()` is not touched at all.

However, `try-catch` only works with Exceptions, but `fopen()` doesnt throw any.

Today something like this is "not so good" style. Use exceptions instead of hard abortion

```
if (!($res = fopen($site, 'r'))) throw new Exception ("Reading of $site failed");
```

Answer (score 0):

or die happens with the first command fails.

It is similar to a try catch, but this is more direct approach.

Note that this is a classical test:

```
fopen($site,"r") or die("Unable to connect to $site");
```

Only if fopen($site,"r") returns false, will the second half of the test be run: 'die('error')'.

Same is if(a || b); b is only run if a returns false.

Die in PHP is the same as exit();
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Stops execution of the current script entirely, and prints out the error message.

Comment: Its not similar to `try-catch`.

Comment: _Similar_ to try catch as in, it trys the first statement, and on false, executes the second. Or on true, does not execute the second statement, or 'catch'. I was commenting on the posters question 'Why would you use this instead of a try catch block? ' Where as try/catch is on error, this is on boolean.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it equals ||

In this case it is explicitly stopping the execution of the page and printing that error message.

Comment: It's not equal... It has a different precedence...