# PHP if statement: use "OR" or ||?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, pipe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - and / or keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502092/php-and-or-keywords)

```
if($foo == 0 or $bar == 1 || $baz == 2)
{
    ...
}
```

Is it better to use "or" or || and is there any significant difference between them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's basically a matter of choice.

There *is* a difference however, when it comes to [operand precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php):

```php
if ( false && false || true ) // true

if ( false AND false || true ) // false
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/zvFPzR

Comment: personally, I've grown accustom to just using || since that is universal in most languages. Not all languages allow `OR`