# Why (false and false or true) returns true

Tags: php, operators, operator-precedence

```
var_dump(false and false || true);
// result: bool(false)
```

`(false and false || true)` returns false as expected.

```
var_dump(false and false or true);
// result: bool(true)
```

but `(false and false or true)` returns true. I have no logical explanation why this is happening.

Comment: I suppose first place to look in is manual. Where there's clear explanation about [operators precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: thanks guys. I've just got it carved in my brain that `||` and `or` are equivalent for some reason

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`&&` and `||` have higher precedence on `and` and `or`

You can see [Operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) on PHP documentation

So

```
<?php 
var_dump(false and false || true);
// eq: false and (true or false) => false

var_dump(false and false or true);
// eq: (false and false) or true => true
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

When we sort operators by priority, it´s:

```
&& > || > AND > OR
```

And it´s answer to your question. `||` has higher priority than `AND`.

I suppose you to use only one 'type' of logical operators, use `&&` and `||` or `and` and `or`. Don´t combine them.

Answer (score 0):

Even though logically `||` and `or` are the same, their precendnce is not.

`||` is of a higher precedence than `OR`, therefore they are interpreted differently in your 2 statements. I guess if you add a bracket around, it will have the same results:

```
(false and (false || true));
```

OR

```
(false and (false or true));
```

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502092/php-and-or-keywords)